# Probability of finding all names in a list

Tags: probability

I have eight columns of names. All the names in each column are different. I have a list of 18 names. What is the probability of observing 8 out of the 18 in a single column?

UPDATE 1: The number of names in the eight columns are 431,385,361,291,281,234,200 and 197 respectively. My stats is pretty weak and I am unsure as to how I can do this. I tried going through the card and marble probability questions but nothing seems similar. I saw this done in a published paper and I would like to replicate something similar for a paper I am writing. They listed the P as P<0.002.

UPDATE 2: (18 choose 8)*(2362 choose 10) / (2380 choose 18) is an answer I received from a friend where 2380 is the sum of names in all the columns. Is this correct?

Comment: Statement is incomplete.  How many names in each column?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Note that your friend's answer makes no use of column size. Does it make sense that this probability is independent of how the names are distributed between the columns? If it were, then you would have the same probability when all but one of the columns has 1 name, and the last column has the other 2355. But for that case the probability is obviously 1.